# How would I check a password has met minimum requirements as its being typed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, passwords

I want to validate a password as its being typed in javascript and let the user know when each requirement is met.

My js code so far is

```
//Test password as its being typed
$(document).ready(function () {    
$("#password").keyup(ValidatePassword);
});


//recieve password
function ValidatePassword() {
var password = $("#password").val();


}
```

I have a cs function which validates the password which I want to eventually call when this function is passed.

Here is the validation I am using:

```
ublic static bool ValidatePassword(string password)
    {
        const int MIN_LENGTH = 8;
        const int MAX_LENGTH = 50;

        if (password == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        bool meetsLengthRequirements = password.Length >= MIN_LENGTH && password.Length <= MAX_LENGTH;
        bool hasUpperCaseLetter = false;
        bool hasLowerCaseLetter = false;
        bool hasDecimalDigit = false;

        if (meetsLengthRequirements)
        {
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(c)) hasUpperCaseLetter = true;
                else if (char.IsLower(c)) hasLowerCaseLetter = true;
                else if (char.IsDigit(c)) hasDecimalDigit = true;
            }
        }

        bool isValid = meetsLengthRequirements
                    && hasUpperCaseLetter
                    && hasLowerCaseLetter
                    && hasDecimalDigit
                    ;
        return isValid;

    }
```

I basically want this in javascript first so I can validate?

Comment: Are you asking for someone to translate your code from C# to Javascript?

Comment: You could look it up for tutorials or even libraries that would help you doing that. Here is a quick search result: https://mlitzinger.com/blog/password-validator-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct translation of the C# if that's helpful

```
function validatePassword(password) {
  const minLength = 8, maxLength = 50;

  if (password == null) return false;
  let meetsLengthRequirements = password.length >= minLength && password.length <= maxLength;
  let hasUpperCaseLetter, hasLowerCaseLetter, hasDecimalDigit;

  if (meetsLengthRequirements) {
    for(let c of password) {
      if (c.match(/[A-Z]/)) hasUpperCaseLetter = true;
      if (c.match(/[a-z]/)) hasLowerCaseLetter = true;
      if (c.match(/[0-9]/)) hasDecimalDigit = true;
    }
  }

  return meetsLengthRequirements && hasUpperCaseLetter && hasLowerCaseLetter && hasDecimalDigit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code,

```
function ValidatePassword() {
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
    if (password.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
    } else {
    }

    // Validate capital letters
    var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
    if (password.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {
    } else {
    }

    // Validate numbers
    var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
    if (password.value.match(numbers)) {
    } else {
    }

    // Validate special characters
    var specialChar = /[@#$%]/g;
    if (password.value.match(specialChar)) {
    } else {
    }

    // Validate length
    if (password.value.length == 8) {
    } else {
    }
}
```